# PDF trailer error on pdfs created by PDFBox

Tags: java, pdf, pdf-generation, pdfbox

I try to create a PDF file with PDFBox and then to create from it an image using commercial library jPDFImages (Qoppa software). Yes, i know that PDFBox is able too to create images from PDFs, but for some reasons I need to use commercial library.

I created PDF file and pass it to jPDFImajes, but I have an error: "Unable to find PDF trailer". Qoppa software describe [this error](http://kbdeveloper.qoppa.com/all-libraries/unabletofindpdftrailer).

The problem is seems to be in the PDF trailer, which is created by PDFBox, but I don`t understand how  to set it up in right mode? (I have a problem only with PDFs created with PDFBox)

Here is my code for pdf creation:

```
public void createPDFFromImage( String file) throws Exception {
    PDDocument doc = null;
    try {
        doc = new PDDocument();

        BufferedImage bufferedImage = ImageIO.read(new File(/home/.../files/test.png));
        PDPage page = new PDPage();
        doc.addPage( page );

        PDJpeg ximage = new PDJpeg(doc,bufferedImage, (float) 0.95);

        PDPageContentStream contentStream = new PDPageContentStream(doc, page);

        contentStream.drawXObject(ximage, x, y, W, H);  

        contentStream.close();

        doc.save(file);
    } finally {
        if( doc != null ) {
            doc.close();
        }
    }
}
```

Here is an error from commercial library:

> java.lang.RuntimeException: com.qoppa.pdf.PDFException: Unable to find PDF trailer.
>   Caused by: com.qoppa.pdf.PDFException: Unable to find PDF trailer.

I think the problem is, how do I create pdf. Maybe I need to add some information to the pdf to make it valid?

Comment: Having chosen an image available here and values for `x, y, W` and `H,` I just executed your method and the output looks ok, especially the trailer is where it should be. Thus, the issue is located somewhere else. Have you checked the file generated in your case manually? Are you properly synchronizing the pdf creation and pdf manipulation tasks? Do you have the required permissions for the target file? And the image file? Is enough free space for the result file? Is the png really at the given path? ...

Comment: Does the PDF display with Acrobat Viewer? If not, it might be this bug: issues.apache.org/jira/browse/PDFBOX-2026 It will be fixed in 1.8.5. Or download a snapshot.